# jQuery video mouseover element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have written some lines in jQuery to create video element on mouseover and remove it and replace it with image used create mouseover

**JS File**

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var org = $("img.post-featured-image").attr("src");

            $("div.posters").mouseover(function(){
                $("#loader").css("display","block");        
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#loader").css("display","none");$(".posters").css("background","none");
                    var src= $("span.vid").attr("data-video");
                    var toast='<video src="/test.MP4" loop autoplay></video>';
                    $("img.post-featured-image").before(toast);
                },5000);
            });
            $("div.posters").mouseout(function(){
                $("video").attr("src","");
                $("video").remove();
                $(".posters").css("background","url:('"+org+"')");
                $("#loader").css("display","none");
            });
            $("video").remove();
            setTimeout(function(){$(".posters").css("background-image",'url("'+org+'")');},3000);

        });
        </script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="posters" style="background:url('http://localhost/testing.jpg');width:640px;height:360px;">
    <a class="responsive-featured-image" href="http://localhost/kawarazaki-ke-no-ichizoku-2-episode-4-hentai-stream-and-download/" title="Kawarazaki-ke no Ichizoku 2 Episode 4" style="height:360px;width:640px;" >
        <div style="padding:24% 46%;">
            <div class="sk-cube-grid" id="loader" style="display:none;">
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
            </div>
                    <img class="post-featured-image" alt=""  itemprop="url" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/kawarazaki-ke-no-ichizoku-2-episode-4.jpg" style="display:none;" />
                </a>
        </div>
        <span class="vid" data-video="http://localhost/test.MP4"></span>
```

Still I am not able to get the solution. I wanted something like this. First a image preloads then the main image displays. After that on mouse hover or mouseover, it would create a short preloader for video, then create video element with autoplay and loop with no controls. Once the mouse leaves the div.element, video is destroyed for code and the main image thumnail is back. You can see it is short of video preview on thumbnails. Like youtube and all. Just simple.

So what is wrong with the code?

Comment: It's hard to tell without a Fiddle, but you probably want to use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover/mouseout to avoid bubbling since you have many child elements.

Comment: You can ignore the loader part in that case. I would like you to use JSfiddle or codepen.io whichever you like.